# Sum List of Elements Using Index of List

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, sum

I am trying to find the sum of the kitchen(18.0) and bedroom area (10.75)

```
# Create the areas list
 areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0, "living room", 20.0, "bedroom", 
10.75, "bathroom", 9.50]

 # Sum of kitchen and bedroom area: eat_sleep_area
 eat_sleep_area = sum(areas[3],areas[-3])

 # Print the variable eat_sleep_area
 print(eat_sleep_area)
```

but when I try to run the code it says this :
      TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
Also I observed that when I used other functions like min,max it works just fine 
can anyone explain me the reason for this?

Comment: `sum`'s first item should be an iterable. You're passing float. What you need is to just add them together.

Comment: if you want to add two or more variables why not using + operator?!

Comment: Try that examples

    areas_map = dict(zip(areas[::2], areas[1::2]))
    eat_sleep_area = areas_map['hallway'] + areas_map['living room']
    
    areas_tup = tuple(zip(areas[::2], areas[1::2]))
    areas_tup[3][1] + areas_tup[-3][1]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a dictionary, not a list, for this kind of thing:

```
areas = {
    'hallway': 11.25,
    'kitchen': 18.0,
    'living room': 20.0,
    'bedroom': 10.75,
    'bathroom': 9.50,
}
```

Then you can sum them like so:

```
result = areas['kitchen'] + areas['bedroom']
```

Dictionaries allow lookup by key. [Check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more.

Answer (score 3):

In Python `sum(iterable[, start])` requires iterable as first argument. Consider just wrapping your arguments in a list like:

```
sum([areas[3],areas[-3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you use a dictionary:

```
areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0, "living room", 20.0, "bedroom", 10.75, "bathroom", 9.50]
areas = { name : measures for name, measures in zip(areas, areas[1:])}
result = sum(areas[name] for name in ('kitchen', 'bedroom'))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
28.75
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum() function adds start and items of the given iterable from left to right.

sum() Parameters
iterable - iterable (list, tuple, dict etc) whose item's sum is to be found. Normally, items of the iterable should be numbers.
start (optional) - this value is added to the sum of items of the iterable. The default value of start is 0 (if omitted)

float is  not iterable

Answer (score 0):

Can replace `sum` with `add` operator

```
from operator import add
eat_sleep_area = add(areas[3],areas[-3]) # if you have only two entities to add otherwise use sum and pass an iterator
```

or with sum

```
eat_sleep_area = add([areas[3],areas[-3]])
```